# CFURLRef requires a bridged cast error

Tags: objective-c, ios, url, audio

I'm trying to get a sound to play but when I code:

```
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((CFURLRef) alertSound, &soundFileObject);
```

it throws the following error:

**Cast of Objective-C pointer type 'NSURL *' to C pointer type 'CFURLRef' (aka 'const struct __CFURL *') requires a bridged cast error**

I have tried both of the two following suggested solutions:

```
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((__bridge CFURLRef) alertSound, &soundFileObject);
```

or

```
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((CFURLRef) CFBridgingRetain(alertSound), &soundFileObject);
```

But I still can't get the sound to play.

I guess the question is: is the bridging error the cause of the sound not playing, or should I be looking else where?

I can get the sound to play using the SysSound sample code and I'm using iOS 6 and Xcode 4.5.

Thanks for any pointers :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cast is probably not the reason the sound is not playing:

```
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((__bridge CFURLRef) alertSound, &soundFileObject);
```

is fine.

Most likely your error is in code that you have not shown us. A common problem is an error in the URL creation or an invalid file format.

Modify your code as follows:

```
OSStatus status = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)alertSound, &soundFileObject);
NSLog(@"AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID status = %ld", status);
```

and check what status code you get; `parmErr` (-50) is relatively common and usually means your URL is nil.

Oh, and one more thought, you don't show where you're actually playing the sound. You do know that `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` does not actually play the sound. You need to call:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundFileObject);
```

Apologies if you knew that already!

Comment: Yep, -50.

My NSURL looks like this:

        NSURL *alertSound   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"tap" withExtension: @"aif"];

And the file "tap.aif" is located in a group I created called Sounds.

Is there somewhere specific that it needs to be placed?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to be sure check in the debugger or with an `NSLog` that the URL is indeed nil. This would mean that (as I think you are beginning to suspect) that Xcode is not copying your sound into your app's bundle. You could try removing it (reference only!!!!) from you project and re-adding it and also double checking that the spelling of the file name is correct (could it be .aiff ?). I don't think you need to put it anywhere special. I usually put such things in the "Supporting Files" group that Xcode creates, but I do not think that is required.

Comment: Ah, got it! Thanks! :)

Not sure why that hadn't added properly in the first place.

Cheers, idz!